# jQuery: Alert Retrieved JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I want to retrieve some json, which I have on my local webserver. But the success-callback isn't called, yet. The json is valid. I've checked it via json lint. This is my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

   $.ajax({
          url: 'http://local-website/json-api/94126',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: data,
          success: getit
          });

   function getit(data){
       alert(data);
   }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Maybe try adding an `error` handler too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed some of your code when putting it on here?

You're missing an opening `<script type='text/javascript'>` tag.

You're also missing a call to `$(document).ready();`

Are you including the jquery library? It's not shown in your document's `<head>`

The data parameter too, is it actually assigned?

The complete function is called whether success of failure of an ajax request, try it instead, and analyse the response in the console:

```
//make sure data is assigned
var data = 'foo';
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://pvtv/toppv-json-api/946',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: data,
          complete: function(data){console.log(data);};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing `var data = { some : 'some' }`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var data = {};

                $.ajax({
                    url: '../stat.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: getit
                });

              function getit(data){ alert(data); }

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question lies here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. Your protocols are different: file and http.

You can only make calls from (and to) the same domain and protocol. It's a security issue.

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer to use $.getJSON.

```
$.getJSON('http://pvtv/toppv-json-api/946', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is just a wrapper for the code in the question. It won't help fix the issue.

Comment: Please read my second post in this thread. I've answered on my own question and now my post isn't "right placed" in this thread.

Comment: I've tried $.getJSON and $.ajax even with a text.json file in the same folder as the html-file with the jquery: always there's the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" problem. Has anybody an idea how to solve that?

Comment: The error message: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." is visible in google chrome. In safari $.getJSON works.. :-/